# cannot load models within mountable engine on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, bundle, rails-engines

I have a rails project which uses mongo db, and I wrote an mountable engine named 'report_service'.

I used it like this in main rails project:

`gem 'report_service', :git => 'git@xx.com:report_service.git', :branch => :master, :require => false`

I don't want this gem loaded when the rails project is initialized, so I added the `:require => false` option.

But in my rails console, after I execute `require 'report_service'`, I cannot find models in this gem.

```
[1] pry(main)> ReportService
=> ReportService
[2] pry(main)> ReportService::Engine
NameError: uninitialized constant ReportService::Engine
from (pry):2:in `<main>'
[3] pry(main)> require 'report_service'
=> true
[4] pry(main)> ReportService::Engine
=> ReportService::Engine
[5] pry(main)> ReportService::RsExam
NameError: uninitialized constant ReportService::RsExam
from (pry):5:in `<main>'
```

Here is my report_service gem directory and code:

report_service/lib/report_service.rb

```
require "active_record/railtie"
require "report_service/engine"
module ReportService
end
```

report_service/lib/report_service/engine.rb

```
module ReportService
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
   isolate_namespace ReportService
  end
end
```

report_service/app/models/report_service/rs_exam.rb

```
module ReportService
  class RsExam < ActiveRecord::Base
  end
end
```

Comment: have you tried loading your gem at initialisation? and then trying?

Comment: it's ok if I remove ':required => false', but this is not I want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scrap that update. Just add `require "report_service/rs_exam"` into your `report_service.rb`.

```
require "active_record/railtie"
require "report_service/engine"
require "report_service/rs_exam"
module ReportService
end
```

My reasoning is that what is happening is that your loading the model `report_service/rs_exam` which is why you will get an uninitialized constant error. Because looking at the console output.

Loading the gem works fine.

```
require 'report_service'
=> true
```

The ReportService::Engine is loaded fine.

```
[4] pry(main)> ReportService::Engine
=> ReportService::Engine
```

But then when you try to load the rs_exam

```
[5] pry(main)> ReportService::RsExam
NameError: uninitialized constant ReportService::RsExam
from (pry):5:in `<main>'
```

you get your uninitialized constant error because it has not been required. Try that and let me know how you get on

Comment: `class Engine < ::Rails::Engine` is generated default by `rails plugin new blorgh --mountable`, it will get the same error while i remove semi-colons before `Rails::Engine`, this is not the problem, because after `require 'report_service'`, I can load `ReportService::Engine`, the problem is i cannot load models in engine, like this error `[5] pry(main)> ReportService::RsExam
NameError: uninitialized constant ReportService::RsExam`

Comment: Have you mounted this correctly, is it plugged into your routes?

Comment: if I used `gem 'report_service', :git => 'git@xx.com:report_service.git', :branch => :master`, everything is ok, but I add ':required => false' options, because I don't want this gem loaded when rails project initialized

Comment: @RichieMin another thing that came to mine you are doing `:require => false`. I hope you are aware of what this does. What your saying is in your gemfile you register that gem as a dependency **WITHOUT** it being required. To my understanding if I am correct the reason why you did this was because you wanted to just register it and not loaded. So anyways in your production mode you will need to require it. Once again add that require line that I suggested.

Comment: @RichieMin if this answer has helped you with your question mark it complete

Comment: sorry @David, I checked it late, just now, I found I must add `Dir[ReportService::Engine.root + 'app/models/**/*.rb'].collect{ |f| require f }` this line to lib/report_service.rb, load models manually by this would fix my question, I don't know there is whether another solution.